# Can you help me to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{-1+\cosh (2x)}dx$ as $\pi^2/6$? And do you find a similar integral for $\zeta(4)$?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, closed-form, hyperbolic-functions

I was inspired in the shape of the integrals for $\zeta(2)$ in **A. Córdoba,** *Encounters at the interface between Number Theory and Harmonic Analysis*, Proceedings of the Segundas Jornadas de Teoría de Números, page 102 (2007) **Biblioteca de la Revista Matemática Iberoamericana**, to ask to [Wolfram Alpha online calculator](https://www.wolframalpha.com) about integrals of a different kind, to obtain integrals that get zeta values.

> **Example 1.** After a lot of trials with **Wolfram Alpha** I've found (**here was fixed a typo, see the comments from the users, thanks them**) $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{-1+\cosh (2x)}dx=\frac{\pi^2}{6}.$$

When I did the change of variables $u=e^{2x}$ I can show (using the change of variables and the evaluation from Wolfram Alpha) that previous integral is evaluated as $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\log^2 u}{-8u+4u^2+4}du=\frac{\pi^2}{6},$$ 
**see it:**

integrate (log x)^2/(-8x+4x^2+4) dx from x=0 to x=infinite

> **Example 2.** After a lot experiments, I would like to get $\frac{\pi^4}{90}$ as an integral of previous kind, I say a double integral, and not a multiple of an integral of this kind, some of my attempts were, for example (in comments you can see an ample variety) this
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2y^2}{(-1+\cosh (2x))(1+\cosh(y)))}dxdy=\frac{\pi^4}{9},$$
>   or this
>   $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2y^2}{(1+\cosh (2x))(1+\cosh( \sqrt{5}y)))}dxdy=\frac{\pi^4}{90\sqrt{5}}.$$ In comments are more of my attempts to get a similar integral for $\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4}{90}$.

These are **the codes of previous Example 2:**

integrate x^2y^2/((-1+cosh(2x))(1+cosh(y)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty

integrate x^2y^2/((1+cosh(2x))(1+cosh(sqrt(5)y)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty

I would like to know

> **Question.** Can you provide to me hints to finish the calculation $\int_0^\infty\frac{\log u}{-8u+4u^2+4}du=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$? Can you obtain an integral, not a multiple of an integral of previous kind (see also the comments) to get $\zeta(4)$? **Many thanks.**

Comment: integrate x^2y^2/((-1+cosh(2x))(-1+cosh(2y)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty  (next)   

integrate x^2y^2/((-1+cosh(x))(-1+cosh(y/2)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty   (next)   

integrate x^2y^2/((-1+cosh(x))(1+cosh(y/2)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty    (next)   

integrate x^2y^2/((1+cosh(x))(1+cosh(y)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty    (next)

Comment: integrate x^2y^2/((1+cosh(x))(1+cosh(y)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty  (next) 

integrate x^2y^2/((-1+cosh(x))(1+cosh(y)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty  (next) 

integrate x^2y^2/((1+cosh(2x))(-1+cosh(y)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty  (next) 

integrate x^2y^2/((1+cosh(2x))(-1+cosh(sqrt(5*2)y)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty  (next) 

integrate x^2y^2/((-1+cosh(2x))(-1+cosh(sqrt(10)y)))dx dy from x=-infty to x=infty, from y=-infty to y=infty

Comment: The integral in your question diverges.

Comment: @user243301 I think there is a typo in your first integral, the result is *not* $\frac{\pi^2}6$, it's rather $\frac43 \pi^2 \approx 13.15947\cdots$. See my answer below.

Comment: Very thanks much, you are rigth, thus I'm sorry @AhmedS.Attaalla There was a typo, that now will fix, the right code was                     integrate x^2/(-1+cosh(2x)) dx from x=-infinite to x=infinite

Comment: Very thanks much and I'm sorry @OlivierOloa There was a typo, that now will fix, the right code was                     integrate x^2/(-1+cosh(2x)) dx from x=-infinite to x=infinite

Comment: **Since was mistakes in my Question, I hope and accept now, answers for this from an open viewpoint.** These answers then **will be** here as **the best reference for all users of this site Mathematics Stack Exchange.** Then in a week I will choose one of them. Very thanks much for the patience of all users.

Comment: It's better to give the right integral in the title, that's why I've edited it ;)

Comment: In general:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{s-1}}{a \cosh x+b\sinh x+c}\,dx=\frac{\Gamma(s)}{\sqrt{b^2+c^2-a^2}} \left(\operatorname{Li}_s \left(\frac{\sqrt{b^2+c^2-a^2}-c}{a+b}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_s \left(-\frac{\sqrt{b^2+c^2-a^2}+c}{a+b}\right)\right).$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *Can you help me to evaluate $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{-1+\cosh (2x)}dx$ as $\pi^2/6$?*
>
> *And can you find a similar integral for $\zeta(4)$?*

**Hint**. One may observe that, for $p\ge1$, one has
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^{2p}}{-1+\cosh(2x)}dx&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2p}}{-1+\cosh(2x)}dx
\\\\&=2\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2p}}{-1+\dfrac{e^{2x}+e^{-2x}}2}dx
\\\\&=4\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{2p}\:e^{-2x}}{(1-e^{-2x})^2}dx
\\\\&=4\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\int_0^\infty x^{2p}e^{-2nx}dx
\\\\&=4\:\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(2p+1)}{2^{2p+1}n^{2p}}
\\\\&= \frac1{2^{2p-1}}\:\Gamma(2p+1)\zeta(2p).
\end{align}
$$ Then, taking for example $p=1$ and $p=2$, one gets

> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^2}{-1+\cosh (2x)}dx&=\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2 }6
> \\\\ \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{x^4}{-1+\cosh(2x)}dx&=3\zeta(4)=\frac{\pi^4 }{30}.
> \end{align}
> $$

Comment: I've modified the question, and I vote up your good answer, very thanks much for your hints that now I will read. I am wait about a week, and after I will accept an answer. Notice that but my mistake and my clumsiness (= torpeza in spanish) the question was modified.

Comment: Also closed your forms are nice Olivier Oloa!

Comment: @user243301 I've edited my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: You are quick! Very thanks much one more time for your results.

Comment: @user243301 Since $\cosh 2x-1=\sinh^2x$, one might consider the general form of
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{\sinh^2bx}\ dx=2\cdot\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1-e^{bx}}\ dx
$$

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 How do you define $x^{a-1}$ when $x<0$? Also If you want to transform $\int_{-\infty}^\infty$ into $2 \cdot \int_0^\infty$ you have to be careful with the exponent of $x^{a-1}$. Don't you think so?

Comment: @OlivierOloa Yes, I'm aware of that. So, in this case we may choose a certain value for $a-1$, say it must an even integer.

Comment: Then the generalization $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{u^{a-1}}{\sinh^2bu}\ du$ could be obtained from $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a-1}}{-1+\cosh(2x)}\ dx$ by the change of variable $x=bu$, directly.

Comment: A vey nice formula, @Anastasiya-Romanova秀 feel free then to add your approach. Very thanks much for your contribution.